# Formatting local timestamps with WinRT

Tags: datetime, windows-runtime, c++-cx

WinRT uses the [DateTimeFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter.aspx) class to turn timestamps into human-readable dates. In C++CX, you'll pass it a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.foundation.datetime.aspx) instance, which contains a timestamp in UTC time, and let it work its magic.

However, I have an application that consumes timestamps in *local* time. I'd like to format them and show them to my users, but if I pass the timestamp as is, the DateTimeFormatter will assume that it's UTC and will try to convert it to local time again, resulting in incorrect times.

How can I display local time with WinRT? Is there a way to turn back local time into UTC time?

The timestamps are generated from the machine that consumes them, so there is no risk of timezone confusion. It would also be technically feasible to produce UTC timestamps instead, but this would be rather inconvenient and I'd like to fall back to that only if it's the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thankfully, FileTimeToSystemTime, TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime and SystemTimeToFileTime are all available to Windows store apps. With that, it's possible to create a function to change local back to UTC.

```
uint64 LocalTimeToUtcTime(uint64 local)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER largeTime;
    largeTime.QuadPart = local;

    FILETIME intermediate;
    intermediate.dwHighDateTime = largeTime.HighPart;
    intermediate.dwLowDateTime = largeTime.LowPart;

    SYSTEMTIME systemLocal, systemUtc;
    if (!FileTimeToSystemTime(&intermediate, &systemLocal))
    {
        // handle error
    }

    if (!TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime(nullptr, &systemLocal, &systemUtc))
    {
        // handle error
    }

    if (!SystemTimeToFileTime(&systemUtc, &intermediate))
    {
        // handle error
    }

    largeTime.HighPart = intermediate.dwHighDateTime;
    largeTime.LowPart = intermediate.dwLowDateTime;
    return largeTime.QuadPart;
}
```

Comment: This is reasonable, assuming your input is suitable to interpret as a localized `FILETIME`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Windows::Globalization::Calendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.globalization.calendar.aspx) class to work with local time, or with time in any time zone.

The `Calendar` defaults to the local time zone if you don't explicitly set one.  You can then use `GetDateTime()` to retrieve a `Windows::Foundation::DateTime` instance that can be used with `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
Calendar^ cal = ref new Calendar();
cal->SetToMin();
cal->Year = 2014;
cal->Month = 7;
cal->Day = 14;
cal->Hour = 12;
cal->Minute = 34;
cal->Second = 56;
DateTime dt = cal->GetDateTime();

DateTimeFormatter^ dtf = ref new DateTimeFormatter("shortdate shorttime");
String^ result = dtf->Format(dt);
Logger::WriteMessage(result->Data());
```

Comment: I imagine that I'd use FileTimeToSystemTime with my timestamp to get the information I need to populate it?

Comment: I suppose it depends on exactly what format your timestamps are in.  An example would be useful.

Comment: Expressed in slices of 100ns since Jan 1st, 1601, as returned by `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`.

Comment: Now that I'm back at it, I find that Calendar would be very convenient to work with if I had to make up a date from its human-readable representation, but it's not very good at taking a local timestamp (with the same format as DateTime's UniversalTime) and make it universal.

Comment: Personally, I detest `Windows::Globalization::Calendar`.  It reminds me too much of `java.util.Calendar`...   If you have a better route, then by all means - use it. :)

Comment: Regarding `FILETIME` - technically, they're supposed to *always* be UTC based.  Of course, then there are functions like `FileTimeToLocalFileTime` and `LocalFileTimeToFileTime` that violate that.  Which, BTW have some very interesting flaws [as remarked in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724490(v=vs.85).aspx).